# param-grid passing parameters to an underlying function. lost in kw_args

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, keyword-argument

I am lost here. Hope some one can shed some light.

I have built a pipeline (sklearn pipe, actually to be precise an imbalanced-learn [pipeline](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/dev/generated/imblearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html#imblearn.pipeline.make_pipeline))

The first step of the pipe is a [FunctionSampler](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/dev/generated/imblearn.FunctionSampler.html#imblearn.FunctionSampler) (imbalanced-learn 0.4.0dev available on Git-hub only) which is an API wrapper for a custom function defined below on step #3. I wish to be able to pass a range of parameters to the function underlying - this is my problem here.

Then I build a grid search with a range for max_samples, but when I fit I get the error.

I am new to python - apologies if I there is an obvious answer I am not seeing.

Thanks a lot!

## 1 define custom function

```
In [90]: def outlier_rejection(X, y, max_samples):
        ...:     model = IsolationForest(max_samples=max_samples, contamination=0.4, random_state=rng)
        ...:     model.fit(X)
        ...:     y_pred = model.predict(X)
        ...:     return X[y_pred ==1], y[y_pred == 1]
        ...:
```

## 2 build pipeline

```
  pipe = make_pipeline(FunctionSampler(func=outlier_rejection, kw_args={'max_samples':1}), LogisticRegression(random_state=rng))
```

## 3 show the pipe I need to pass max_samples in kw_args

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
             steps=[('functionsampler', FunctionSampler(accept_sparse=True,
                func=<function outlier_rejection at 0x000001173B3E9EA0>,
                kw_args={'max_samples': 1})), ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                  intercept_scaling=1, max...ect at 0x0000011737DCA1B0>,
                  solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False))])
```

## 4 build a grid search

```
cv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid={'logisticregression__C': [1., 10.], 'functionsampler__max_samples': [1, 10, 100]})
```

## 5 fit cv and get the following error

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter max_samples for estimator FunctionSampler(accept_sparse=True,
        func=<function outlier_rejection at 0x000001173B3E9EA0>,
        kw_args={'max_samples': 1}). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that you're trying to pass a `max_samples` argument to `FunctionSampler()`, but `FunctionSampler()` does not have a `max_samples` as a named argument.

Rather, `max_samples` belongs as an entry in the `kw_args` argument to `FunctionSampler()`.

That suggests that you should instead pass in something like

```
'functionsampler__kw_args': {'max_samples': [1, 10, 100]}
```

to the `GridSearchCV` `param_grid` argument (note: I'm not sure why it's called `params` in your code, the argument is either positional or named `param_grid` in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)).

But...you can't pass a dict as a value in the `param_grid` argument.  Doing so throws an error:

> ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (functionsampler__kw_args) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray.

The best solution I can think of is to wrap `FunctionSampler()` in a class that accepts separate `key` and `values` arguments from `param_grid` (eg `functionsamplerwrapper__key`), and then puts them together as the `kw_args` dict that `FunctionSampler()` expects.  Something like this:

```
from imblearn import FunctionSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


class FunctionSamplerWrapper(object):    
    def unwrap(self, key, values):
        return FunctionSampler(func=outlier_rejection, kw_args={key[0]: values})

pipe = make_pipeline(FunctionSamplerWrapper().unwrap(key = ['max_samples'], 
                                                     values = [1]), 
                     LogisticRegression(random_state=rng))

cv = GridSearchCV(pipe, 
                  [{'logisticregression__C': [1., 10.], 
                   'functionsamplerwrapper__key': ['max_samples'],
                   'functionsamplerwrapper__values': [1, 10, 100]}])
```

Note - I only checked to see if this runs without error (it does), but I haven't actually tested it out on data to ensure correct functionality.
Hope this helps.

Comment: super! thank you very much indeed. Re: "params" and "param_grid" is due to the fact that i was experimenting with a variation of GridSearchCV called EvolutionaryAlgorithmSearchVC (sklearn-deap)

Comment: Also I just want to mention that while playing I managed to make this code run: cv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid={'logisticregression__C': [1., 10.], 'functionsampler__kw_args': [{'max_samples':x} for x in [10,100]]}) but I need to test it fully

Comment: You're welcome!  Re different variations, it might be helpful to update your original post to note which functions and classes are non-standard.  I also discovered that your `make_pipeline` is actually from `imblearn`, not `sklearn` (the `sklearn` version throws an error with this code).  For others coming to learn from your post in the future, this might be cause for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The `FunctionSamplerWrapper` solution by @andrew_reece isn't working for me. Instead, the workaround in the comments by @luide does the job. Only instead of

`'functionsampler__kw_args': [{'max_samples':x} for x in [10,100]]`

I'd prefer to do

`'functionsampler__kw_args': [{'max_samples': 10}, {'max_samples': 100}]`

because I think it's easier to understand.

Note that I haven't placed the values inside lists (e.g. `{'max_samples': [10]}`), because doing so generates an error about non-matching value lengths.

There's a relevant discussion about Scikit-learn's `FunctionTransformer` here:

[How can I make the FunctionTransformer along with GridSearchCV into a pipeline？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584012/how-can-i-make-the-functiontransformer-along-with-gridsearchcv-into-a-pipeline)

To sum up, that's how I would do it:

`'functionsampler__kw_args': [{'max_samples': 10}, {'max_samples': 100}]`