# How can I make the FunctionTransformer along with GridSearchCV into a pipeline？

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Basically, I want to treat the column index as a hyperparameter. Then tune this hyperparameter along with other model hyperparameters in the pipeline. In my example below, the `col_idx` is my hyperparameter. I self-defined a function called `log_columns` that can perform log transformation on certain columns and the function can be passed into `FunctionTransformer`. Then put FunctionTransformer and model into the pipeline.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


def log_columns(X, col_idx = None):
    log_func = np.vectorize(np.log)
    if col_idx is None:
        return X
    for idx in col_idx:
        X[:,idx] = log_func(X[:,idx])
    return X

pipe = make_pipeline(FunctionTransformer(log_columns, ), PCA(), SVC())
param_grid = dict(functiontransformer__col_idx = [None, [1]],
              pca__n_components=[2, 5, 10],
              svc__C=[0.1, 10, 100],
              )

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid)
digits = load_digits()

res = grid_search.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
```

Then, I received the following error message:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter col_idx for estimator 
FunctionTransformer(accept_sparse=False, check_inverse=True,
      func=<function log_columns at 0x1764998c8>, inv_kw_args=None,
      inverse_func=None, kw_args=None, pass_y='deprecated',
      validate=None). Check the list of available parameters with 
`estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I am not sure if `FunctionTransformer` allows me to do what I expected. If not, I am eager to know other elegant methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`col_idx` is not a valid parameter for `FunctionTransformer` class, but `kw_args` is.
`kw_args` is a dictionary of additional keyword arguments of `func`. In your case,
the only keyword argument is `col_idx`.

Try this:

```py
param_grid = dict(
    functiontransformer__kw_args=[
        {'col_idx': None},
        {'col_idx': [1]}
    ],
    pca__n_components=[2, 5, 10],
    svc__C=[0.1, 10, 100],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should check params, that you can adjust: `pipe.get_params().keys()`.

After, please, have a look into the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search) on how to organize `param_grid`.